# No se permite EditItem para esta vista?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

estoy creando un datagrid en mi proyecto de wpf y quiero que los usuarios sean capaces de escribir directamente en el datagrid, he puesto entre sus propiedade el IsreadOnly en falso y can user add rows en true, cuando le doy start a la aplicación me sale la fila en blanco pero cuando doy click en ella para escribir me sale un error  No se permite EditItem para esta vista.Les dejo el código, si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

```
<Grid Margin="20">
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridXAMAL1"  
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  SelectionChanged="DataGridXAMAL1_SelectionChanged"  
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="False"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  CanUserAddRows="True"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                  MinRowHeight="40">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Teal"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Corbel"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Etapa" Binding="{Binding Periods}"  Width="*" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inicio" Binding="{Binding Start1}" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Terminacion" Binding="{Binding Finish}" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tareas" Binding="{Binding Homework}" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instituciones" Binding="{Binding Institutions}" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Recursos " Binding="{Binding Financial}" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Materiales" Binding="{Binding Material}" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resultado" Binding="{Binding Results}" MinWidth="100" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salidas" Binding="{Binding Out}" MinWidth="100" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBox x:Name="Financial" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32" Margin="229,315,451,0"  Text="Recursos" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15" TextAlignment="Center"  AcceptsReturn="True" MouseEnter="Financial_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="Financial_OnMouseLeave"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AppResults" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  Margin="596,314,84,0" Text="Resultado"  TextAlignment="Center"  Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15"  AcceptsReturn="True" MouseEnter="AppResults_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="AppResults_OnMouseLeave"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AppHomework" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  Margin="596,251,84,0" Text="Tareas"  TextAlignment="Center"   Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15"  AcceptsReturn="True" MouseEnter="AppHomework_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="AppHomework_OnMouseLeave"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AppPeriod" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  Margin="32,249,648,0" Text="Etapa" TextAlignment="Center"  Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15"  AcceptsReturn="True" MouseEnter="AppPeriod_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="AppPeriod_OnMouseLeave"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Institutions" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  Margin="32,314,648,0"  Text="Instituciones"  TextAlignment="Center"  Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15"  AcceptsReturn="True" MouseEnter="Institutions_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="Institutions_OnMouseLeave"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AppOut" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32" Margin="342,377,338,0"  Text="Salidas" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextAlignment="Center"  Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15"   AcceptsReturn="True" MouseEnter="AppOut_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="AppOut_OnMouseLeave"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AppFinish1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="416,250,264,0" Text="Actividades"  TextAlignment="Center"  Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15"  AcceptsReturn="True" MouseEnter="AppFinish1_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="AppFinish1_OnMouseLeave"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AppStart1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Column="0" Margin="229,249,451,0"  Text="Inicio"  TextAlignment="Center"  Foreground="Gray" FontSize="15"  AcceptsReturn="True" MouseEnter="AppStart1_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="AppStart1_OnMouseLeave"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Material" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32" Margin="416,314,264,0"  Text="Materiales" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="15" Foreground="Gray" TextAlignment="Center"  AcceptsReturn="True" MouseEnter="Material_OnMouseEnter"  MouseLeave="Material_OnMouseLeave"/>
        <Button Content="Insertar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="999,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Click="BtnAddPeriod_Cliked" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="18"/>
        <Button Content="Borrar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="999,377,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Click="BtnDeletePeriod_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.947,0" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="18"/>
        <Button Content="Modificar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="999,312,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Click="BtnModificarPeriod_Click" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="18"/>
        <Button Content="Guardar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1157,312,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="18"/>
        <Button Content="Cargar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1157,375,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="18"/>
        <Button Content="Limpiar Tabla" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1157,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Background="Gray" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Corbel" FontSize="18" Click="Button_Click"/>


    </Grid>
```

// método para añadir elementos al datagrid

```
private void BtnAddPeriod_Cliked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Period tempPeriod = new Period
            {

                Periods = AppPeriod.Text,
               Start1 = AppStart1.Text,
                Finish = AppFinish1.Text,
               Homework = AppHomework.Text,
              Financial = Financial.Text,
               Material = Material.Text,
              Results = AppResults.Text,
              Out = AppOut.Text,
              Institutions = Institutions.Text
          };

          DataGridXAMAL1.Items.Add(tempPeriod);
}
```

Comment: El tema es el source del gird.. es editable?

Comment: realmente no se a que se refiere,soy nuevo en wpf

Comment: El binding de tu grilla, que tipo de objeto tiene detras?

Comment: en el codigo de atras tengo una clase que contiene cada uno de los elementos que va a contener las columnas de mi datagrid, el tipo de datos de cada uno de esos elementos es de tipo string

Comment: Y esos objetos estan en alguna clase de lista?

Comment: no estan incluidos en ninguna lista

Comment: y como los pasas a la grilla? si la grilla no tiene algun tipo de lista atras, entonces no va a poder generar nuevos registros. La grilla no crea objetos por si misma...

Comment: El datagrid lo lleno mediante los textbox q tengo y un boton añadir con el código que pondré a continuación en la pregunta

Comment: Claro.. pero la grilla, no sabe hacer eso.. si vos queres que la grilla genere nuevos elementos, la grilla tiene que tener como source una lista...

Comment: Gracias gibianchi por la ayuda,finalmente lo logre hacer,

Comment: List<Period> periods=new List<Period>();
            Period period=new Period();
            periods.Add(period);
            DataGridXAMAL1.ItemsSource = periods;

Comment: Hice eso atras y en el xaml lo q hice fue bindear el datagrid